# File not found error even if file is present in FTP

Tags: .htaccess

I have files present in FTP but when I'm trying to access those files (html files) I'm getting "The requested URL was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

My .htaccess file code is this and I have tried some of the solutions but none worked. Can you please tell me what's wrong or missing in htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demosite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /demosite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You will want to review the server error logs, or mod_rewrite logs if those are enabled specifically. But there really isn't enough information here. We need the server relative paths to resources, etc.

Comment: @jdv: Thanks for your input but we only have access to a specific folder on an FTP. The client has not given us root FTP access so we only have that much. Also the folder whose access we have there is a WordPress blog installed in it and the files we are trying to access are not part of that blog. So I guess WordPress is not allowing to access our files and showing this error. Could this be the reason? And will we need client' root access and WordPress access to resolve this issue?